# Multiclass classification of text in R

Tags: r, text, text-mining, random-forest, multiclass-classification

I have build a random forest for multiclass text classification. The model returned an accuracy of 75 %. There are 6 labels, however out of the 6 classes, only 3 are classified and rest are not classified. I would really appreciate if anyone could let me know what went wrong.

Below are the steps i followed.

DATA PREPARATION

- Creat a word vector for description.
- Build a corpus using the word    vector.
- Pre-processing tasks such as removing number, whitespaces,
  stopwords and conversion to lower case.
- Build a document term matrix    (dtm).
- Remove sparse words from the above dtm.
- The above step leads    to a count frequency matrix showing the
  frequency of each word in its    coressponding column.
- Tranform count frequency matrix to a binary       instance matrix,
  which shows occurences of a word in a document as       either 0 or
  1, 1 for being present and 0 for absent.
- Append the    label    column from the original  dataset with
  the transformed   dtm. The    label column has 6 labels.

MODEL BUILDING

- Randomly sample the dtm and split it into a traning set and testing
  set.
- Build a base model of random forest with 7-fold cross    validation.
- Check for accuracy of the model on the training set and    testing
  set.

  I am sharing the link to the results ( if it is allowed here).

  http://rpubs.com/shanmukha_karthik/346007

Comment: 1.  Could you please show us a frequency table of label distribution on training set? As the other 3 labels have less proportion (hence unbalanced data), your training set may have really a few (or none) of those labels.  2. I haven't used rpart for multiclass purpose, but you haven't specify depth of trees, hence model may not split enough for all 6 labels.  3. Could you shows us the model summary to check the depth (or average) of trees?

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu i have added the frequency table of label distribution in training set. check this [link](http://rpubs.com/shanmukha_karthik/346007)

Comment: TBH you might want to try using something different than a Random Forest - your dtm will be a sparse matrix, since in any document, most words in the corpus don't occur. Usually SVM or MNB work better https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P12-2018

Answer (score 0):

There could be many possibilities to increase the accuracy:
**1.** Try to increase the size of classes which have less than 1000 instances. 
**2.** Try to use multiple remove sparse terms threshold such as; 0.991,0.99,0.999, etc. and check your accuracy accordingly
**3.** Use stemming, it used to give you the root form of words
**4.** You are only using Term frequency (TF) while creating your dtm. Try to use tfidf score as well by simply adding.

```
tdm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,
       control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE),stopwords = TRUE))
```

**5.** Try to use another package like; from mlr use rangers to train RandomForest.

I hope it works for you.